# Galvanic cell using NaCl, Cu and Zn, why does it work?

Tags: homework, electrolysis, electronegativity

Got a paper due tomorrow in chemistry, and my friends and I are totally stuck on this:
Basically we mixed some regular salt (NaCl) into a glass of water and stuck a zinc nail and a copper nail into the solution. We connected the nails and measured a voltage of .6V. Why does this happen?

I understand galvanic cells of other types and electrolysis to a pretty OK extent, but I can't for the life of me understand what's happening at a chemical level in this reaction. I also need chemical formulas and the likes. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I want you to try and work out the details yourself, but there's one aspect of this kind of cell that's not straightforward. At one electrode, you have a reduction reaction and at the other, an oxidation, just like any other galvanic cell. In the oxidation reaction, one of the metal electrodes is oxidized to put cations in solution. (think about which metal is more easily oxidized) In the type of galvanic cell that you may be more familiar with, a metal cation in solution is reduced onto the other electrode, but in this case, the only metal cation is $\ce{Na+}$, which is extremely difficult to reduce. Therefore, some other reduction reaction must be happening. The only other reducible substance present is water.

The two reactions occurring can be found on [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_electrode_potential_(data_page)) table, and using the potentials in the table, you should be able to work out which reactions are occurring and at which electrodes.

Comment: Good answer, thanks, but I believe I'm not quite yet informed enough on this subject to quite understand what's happening. This is my first semester of science (meaning only a part of it is chemistry) at school, and I think my teacher made a mistake in assigning this task to us. I found a site that helped me at least get some kind of a solution to this problem, but I'm not 100% sure it's correct: http://sci-toys.com/scitoys/scitoys/echem/batteries/batteries.html

Comment: That is almost the same cell you're thinking of. Unfortunately, their explanation is wrong with only NaCl electrolyte. It's the same as the classic lemon battery, though. Take a look at this: http://surface.syr.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1001&context=che